# Tkinter Scrollbar scrolling down whenever a message is sent

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently am building a chat sort of system using tkinter to create the UI. I currently have it so that whenever a message is sent, it will automatically scroll down to the bottom, however, ideally I would like it to only do this when the scrollbar is already at the down-most position.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TkMain:
    def __init__(self, data, room_id):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title(room_id)
        self.data = data
        self.data_str = ""
        for item in self.data:
            self.data_str += f"{item}\n\n"

        self.chat_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.window)

        self.past_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.chat_frame)

        self.past_texts = tk.Label(master=self.past_frame, text=self.data_str, justify="left", bd=10)

        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(master=self.chat_frame)
        self.scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(master=self.chat_frame, yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)

        for item in self.data:
            self.listbox.see(tk.END)
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, item)

        self.listbox.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH)

        self.scroll.config(command=self.listbox.yview)

        self.past_frame.pack()

        self.input_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.chat_frame)
        self.text_input = tk.Entry(master=self.input_frame)
        self.button = tk.Button(master=self.input_frame, text="Send Message", command=self.send)
        self.text_input.pack()
        self.button.pack()

        self.input_frame.pack()

        self.chat_frame.pack()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def send(self):
        if self.text_input.get() != "":
            message = self.text_input.get()
            self.data.append(message)
            self.text_input.delete(0, "end")
            if self.scroll.get()[0] > 1: #This is the part I am having trouble on.
                self.listbox.insert("end", message)
            else:
                self.listbox.insert("end", message)
                self.listbox.see(tk.END)


test = TkMain(["arstnfunaywnfotunaof"], 1234)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to check for is if the scrollbar is at the bottom. The second item in the list that `self.scroll.get()` returns gives the bottom of scrollbar position. So if the second item of that list is less than 1, the scrollbar is not at the bottom.

Try changing the line in question to `if self.scroll.get()[1] < 1:` So the `send` function looks like:

```
def send(self):
    if self.text_input.get() != "":
        message = self.text_input.get()
        self.data.append(message)
        self.text_input.delete(0, "end")
        if self.scroll.get()[1] < 1:
            self.listbox.insert("end", message)
        else:
            self.listbox.insert("end", message)
            self.listbox.see(tk.END)
```

Comment: You can move `self.listbox.insert("end", message)` outside of the `if` since you do it in both places.  That will remove one bit of redundancy.

Comment: Also you don't need to call `self.text_input.get()` twice.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to `append` and nested `if/else` condition blocks. I usually do `irc` chat similar to PIRCH98.

Snippet code:

```
def send(self):
    if self.text_input.get() is not None:
        message = self.text_input.get()
                
        self.listbox.insert(tk.END, message)
        self.text_input.delete(0, tk.END)
```